# Disable exit on mousemove in cocoa screensaver and build UI?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I want to make an interactive Screensaver with a minimalistic UI. For that I have to disable or override the code exiting the Screensaver on mousemoved. How can I accomplish that?

Also I find it tedious to build and test such Kind of a Screensaver. Would there be any possibility to just build a normal cocoa app and be able to run this as a Screensaver?

I allready searched and tested for hours now.. but to no avail. All examples, tutorials I can find are on normal screensavers.

Ah yes. And the purporse is to port an interactive Windows-Screensaver to MacOS ;)

**EDIT / UPDATE:**

Ok, I'm one step closer. I created a NSButton programmatically and overrided the mousemoveevent. Also I made the Cursor visible inside the mousemoved Event with

`[NSCursor unhide]`

Next step would be to figure out how to override the keyevents, since keyUp and keyDown won't work.

Comment: You may use Screenalicious or SaverLab as the target application in which to debug your screen savers.

Comment: Don't do the [NSCursor unhide] in the MouseMoveEvent handler; use the ScreenSaverView startAnimation method instead; and balance it with a [NSCursor hide] in the stopAnimation method.

Comment: It seems that no matter whether I send [NSCursor unhide] in the mouseMoved event handler or in the startAnimation method, after a short while the cursor is hidden anyway. Putting it in the animateOneFrame method keeps it alive indefinitely. Any idea of a better solution, or what keeps sending [NSCursor hide] behind my back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add these methods to your ScreenSaverView subclass:

```
// override these so mouse movement won't unsave screen
- (void) mouseEntered: (NSEvent *) theEvent;
{}

- (void) mouseExited: (NSEvent *) theEvent;
{}

// override this so modifier keys won't unsave screen
- (void) flagsChanged: (NSEvent *) theEvent;
{
    //gModifierFlags = [theEvent modifierFlags];
}

// override this so key downs won't unsave screen
- (void) keyDown: (NSEvent *) theEvent {
    // if you want a key event to wake the screensaver
    // have it call [super keyDown:theEvent];
} // keyDown
```

Comment: Note to anybody else: you will also need to override the mouseMoved event, if this isn't clear. Andreas was already doing this, so geowar didn't include it redundantly in his answer, but this tripped me up for a few minutes.